Set custom post type to load custom block pattern by default
I have registered a custom block pattern for use on my non-full site editor WordPress theme. The pattern is available to be inserted in default and custom posts. Now I am wondering how it can be set as a pattern that is loaded by default when a user creates a new post for a custom post type.
I have included the pattern registration function and my "work in progress" code for setting the default for a custom post type.
if ( ! function_exists( 'register_document_block_pattern' ) ) :
  function register_document_block_pattern() {
    register_block_pattern(
      'theme-name/document-block-pattern',
      array(
        'title' => __( 'Document Block Pattern', 'theme-name' ),
        'description' => _x( 'A block pattern to display an embedded PDF with a document download link below.', 'Block pattern description', 'theme-name' ),
        'content' => "<!-- wp:pdfemb/pdf-embedder-viewer {\"pdfID\":786,\"url\":\"https://domain.com/rm-template/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/sample-document.pdf\"} /-->\n<!-- wp:file {\"id\":786,\"href\":\"https://domain.com/rm-template/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/sample-financial.pdf\",\"showDownloadButton\":false,\"displayPreview\":false} -->\n<div class=\"wp-block-file\">\n<a href=\"https://domain.com/rm-template/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/sample-financial.pdf\">Sample File</a>\n</div><!-- /wp:file -->\n",
      ),
    );
  }
endif;
add_action( 'init', 'register_document_block_pattern' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'set_document_block_pattern' ) ) :
  function set_document_block_pattern( $editor_settings, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type === 'document' ) {
      $editor_settings['defaultBlockTemplate'] = [
        [
          // Not sure how to correctly load the non-core PDF embedder block
          [['core/file', ['href' => 'https://domain.com/rm-template/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/sample-financial.pdf']]],
        ],
      ];
      return $editor_settings;
    }
  }
endif;
add_filter( 'block_editor_settings_all', 'set_document_block_pattern', 10, 2 );

Note
The website is a WordPress network site. I am not sure if this causes any issues for custom block patterns.

When you call register_post_type() to register your custom post type, one of the args is called template which is described as follows:

Array of blocks to use as the default initial state for an editor session. Each item should be an array containing block name and optional attributes.

So whereever you have the register_post_type(), you could do:
register_post_type(
  'document',
  array(
    …,
    'template' => array(
      array(
        'core/pattern',
        array(
          'slug' => 'theme-name/document-block-pattern',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
);

Or if you want to add the template in some package that is decoupled from the code that calls register_post_type(), you can use the register_{$post_type}_post_type_args hook:
function function_name( $args ) {
  $args['template'] = array(
    array(
      'core/pattern',
      array(
        'slug' => 'theme-name/document-block-pattern',
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_document_post_type_args', 'function_name' );

